# Adding predictors to an intercept-only model

Tags: regression, interaction, interpretation, predictor, intercept

I'm currently testing out a logistic regression model I plan to use to analyse the results of an experiment I'm yet to conduct. I'm running it in R.

My experiment is going to measure whether animals recognise, and therefore choose, a rewarding option (e.g. a blue versus red box, in which only one contains food). The animals will have had a "training" trial to expose them to this option, and then their responses will be recorded in a "test" trial.

I first want to test whether they choose this option more often than would be expected by chance. I therefore start with an intercept-only model as follows:

```
model = glm(choice ~ 1, family = "binomial", data = df)
```

This seems to work fine. But I am confused about adding predictor variables to this model. For example, because the side the rewarding option is presented on in the test trial compared to the training trial may have an effect on choice, I have added a predictor called "sideSame", which has two levels: 0 for no/different and 1 for yes/same.

I'm running different simulations of the data for different potential outcomes. One simulation I am looking at considered that animals choose the rewarding option in the test trial **only when it is on the same side as in the training trial**.

Code:

```
model2 = glm(choice ~ 1 + sideSame, family = "binomial", data = df)
```

So the summary coefficients are:

```
Intercept: Estimate of roughly 0, P > 0.05
SideSame: Strongly positive estimate, P < 0.05
```

The intercept is now the probability of animals choosing the rewarding option when the rewarding option is presented on a **different** side. As expected, it is saying that animals do not choose this option more than can be expected by chance when it is presented on a different side.

My issue is that I'm not totally sure how to interpret this. It seems to me to be an interaction (because whether or not they go for a rewarding option - which is, in a way, a treatment even though it is not written as an explanatory variable - *depends* on which side it's presented on. It also seems to be doing the same thing as including an interaction term does if I included another predictor: if I added, say, animal age (adult or juvenile), the interaction term would tell me how much to add on to the coefficient for "juvenile (sideDifferent)" when the side *for juveniles* is "Same", in the same way that sideSame alone in the model above is telling me how much to add on to the intercept of sideDifferent when the side is "Same".

I'm also considering a few other predictors but worry that I might struggle with their interpretation, so I want to be sure this is the right way to model my data.

I know an alternative would be to code whether animals choose the LEFT or RIGHT option and include whether the rewarding option was on the left or right as a predictor (as well as different/same), but then including other variables would only tell me about their effect on choice of left or right, which is meaningless, so I think I would have to fit them all as interaction terms. This doesn't seem like a better approach, but I'm unsure.

The bottom line is that I need to be able to say definitively whether animals are able to recognise the rewarding option, while also considering potential confounds. Is it appropriate to model my data in this way?

Answer (score 3):

Interactions technically are products between *predictor* variables. So what you have simulated (and seem to have interpreted correctly) is an effect of a single predictor variable (`sideSame`) on your binary *outcome*, which is "whether or not they go for a rewarding option." That's not an interaction.

If you think that there is a systematic difference between left- versus right-side presentations in some respects you could include `leftSide` as an *extra* predictor in your model in addition to `sideSame`, and maybe even an interaction between `leftSide` and `sideSame`, depending on your knowledge of the subject matter.

*In response to comment:*

Two things can be hard to grasp.

First, as you add more predictors, the interpretation of the intercept changes. For dummy/treatment coding, it's the estimated outcome when all categorical predictors are at reference levels and continuous predictors are at 0. So as you add more predictors the intercept is expected to change.

Second, when you include interactions, the interpretation of lower-level regression coefficients changes. A lower-level coefficient for a predictor then is for a case when the *predictors with which it interacts* are at reference or 0 levels.

It can help to write out everything explicitly in terms of the predictors and interactions. Then you plug in various predictor values to see specifically what you are modeling. Let's call the `sideSame` predictor `S` (=1 if training and test side are the same), call `age` `A` (=1 for adult, 0 for juvenile), and call the actual side presented in the test case `L` (=1 if left, 0 if right).

Then a model without interactions would be:

```
choice ~ 1 + S + A + L
```

Plugging in 0 for the 3 predictors, you see that the intercept would be for different training from test side, juvenile age, test side right. Each coefficient is then the *change* from that intercept when the predictor takes the other value.

An interaction between `sideSame` and `age` would be:

```
choice ~ 1 + S + A + L + S:A
```

where the `S:A` interaction is just the product of the individual 0/1 values for `S` and `A`. The intercept is interpreted the same as above, but the `S` coefficient is the value for the `A = 0` case (juvenile), and the `A` coefficient is the value for the `S = 0` case (different train/test sides). The coefficient for `S:A` is the *extra* difference when both `S = 1` and `A = 1`.

Writing out the explicit form of the linear predictor, recognizing that interaction terms are just products of the individual predictors that are involved, is the safest way to avoid arguing yourself into confusion.

Remember that each predictor and interaction term that you add to the model requires a correspondingly larger study. With logistic regression in this type of biological study, you typically need to have about 10-20 cases in the minority outcome class per predictor (including interactions) to avoid overfitting. So to fit the last model with the interaction term you would need on the order of `2 * 60 = 120` observations if the `choice` outcome was evenly divided between rewarding/not.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I realise I wasn't very clear in my original post so I've added more detail/explanation and hope it is better now.

Comment: @Characas I've expanded the answer. Make sure you understand what an "interaction" means in the context of regression: it's just the product of predictors. You can add predictors without necessarily adding interaction terms, depending on just what question you are trying to answer.

Comment: Thanks very much. I do understand all that. What I am unsure of is how to get the overall effect of whether animals go for the rewarding option, when that is the thing that is being measured by the intercept coefficient in the intercept-only model. Side (whether same/different or left/right) are just additional predictors to check for confounds. It seems that adding them means I can't say whether my sample animals (the group as a whole) go for a rewarding option more often than by chance anymore.

Comment: @Characas when you have additional predictors in the model there is no single measure of "whether my sample animals (the group as a whole) go for a rewarding option more often than by chance." There are measures of whether they do so _at specified values of the predictors_; for logistic regression, that would be whether the corresponding linear-predictor value is significantly different from 0. You could specify the set of predictor values that make it least likely that animals choose the reward and show that they do so even at those predictor values.

Answer (score 1):

When interpreting the coefficients, you should be very careful about how the factor variables are coded and confident that you understand it.  For example, if `choice` has two levels, you want to fully understand what level is coded as 0 and 1, because this will define what increases / decreases to the link value mean.

It will be useful to understand exactly what your `choice` variable means and what the levels are.  You might add this information to your question to get a more specific answer.

Comment: Thanks - I've just added more info and hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have two good answers already. But I think your experimental design is less than optimal. What I would do is randomly assign the animals to train and test. Then use "was trained" as an independent variable. You could add a covariate for "side" and another for "color" to see if they change things. You could even add interactions between those two and "was trained" since I think it's at least possible that animals who were not trained would choose on the basis of color or side.

Also, during the training, I would vary the side that had the food. Then "sameside" becomes meaningless and unnecessary.